# C# Problemas con control personalizado (UserControl)

Tags: c#

Estoy construyendo un control que contiene un pictureBox y varios label, necesitaba que pudiese multiplicarse en Items como un Listbox. Lo he construido pero al carga unos 200 productos aproximadamente se pone un poco pesado, cuando arrastro la ventana se nota que es pesado a la CPU le cuesta trabajo hacerlo.

[image: Así se ve el control]

Codigo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace POS451
{
    public partial class ListItem : UserControl
    {

        public delegate void ItemClickDelegate(object sender, ItemSelecionadoArgs e);
        public event ItemClickDelegate ItemClick;

        public ListItem()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Tag = this;
            panel2.Tag = this;
        }

        #region Propiedades
        private string _title = null;
        private string _reseña = null;
        private Image _icono = null;
        private Color _iconBackground;
        private double _precio  = 0;
        private string _sku;
        private float _porcentajeDescuento = 0.0F;

        [Category("Custom Props")]
        public Color IconBackGround
        {
            get { return _iconBackground; }
            set { _iconBackground = value; panel1.BackColor = value; }
        }

        [Category("Custom Props")]
        public string Descripcion
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { _title = value; lblDescripcion.Text = value; lblDescripcion.Tag = this; }
        }

        [Category("Custom Props")]
        public string Reseña
        {
            get { return _reseña; }
            set { _reseña = value; lblDatosExtras.Text = value; lblDatosExtras.Tag = this; }
        }

        [Category("Custom Props")]
        public Image FotoProducto
        {
            get { return _icono; }
            set { _icono = value; pbIcon.Image = value; pbIcon.Tag = this; }
        }

        [Category("Custom Props")]
        public double Precio
        {
            get { return _precio; }
            set { _precio = value; lblPrecio.Text = value.ToString("C0"); lblPrecio.Tag = this; }
        }

        [Category("Custom Props")]
        public string SKU
        {
            get { return _sku; }
            set {
                _sku = value; 
                lblSku.Text = $"SKU: {value}"; lblSku.Tag = this; }
        }

        [Category("Custom Props")]
        public float PorcentajeDescuento
        {
            get => _porcentajeDescuento;
            set
            {
                _porcentajeDescuento = value;
                lblSaleOFF.Text = $"{value}%";
                lblSaleOFF.Tag = this;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        private void ListItem_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.White;
        }

        private void ListItem_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Silver;
        }
        
        private void ListItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //ListItem item = (ListItem)((Control)sender).Tag;
        
            //ItemSelecionadoArgs args = new ItemSelecionadoArgs(item.SKU, item.Descripcion, item.Descuento, item.DatosExtra, (int)item.Precio, (int)item.PrecioMayorista, item.FotoProducto);
            //ItemClick(this, args);
        }

        private void ListItem_DobleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListItem item = (ListItem)((Control)sender).Tag;

            ItemSelecionadoArgs args = new ItemSelecionadoArgs(item.SKU, item.Descripcion, item.Reseña, (int)item.Precio, (float)item.PorcentajeDescuento, item.FotoProducto);
            ItemClick(this, args);
        }

    }



}
```

Para mostrar el control y repartirlo N veces  he puesto dentro de un FlowLayoutPanel y se ve así.

[image: Presentación del control]

Codigo control PanelListItems

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace POS451
{
    public partial class PanelListItems : UserControl
    {
        public delegate void ItemSeleccionadoDelegate(object sender, ItemSelecionadoArgs e);
        public event ItemSeleccionadoDelegate ItemSelecionado;


        public PanelListItems()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private List<ItemProducto> items;

        [Category("Custom Props")]
        public List<ItemProducto> Items
        {
            get { return items; }
            set { items = value; UpdateProductos(); }
        }


        [Category("Custom Props")]
        public void LoadListItem(List<ItemProducto> listItems)
        {
            if (listItems == null)
                return;

            flowLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();

            foreach (Control ctrl in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
                ctrl.Dispose();
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();

            foreach (ItemProducto item in listItems)
            {
                var e =
                    new ListItem
                    {
                        SKU                 = item.Sku,
                        Reseña              = item.Reseña,
                        Descripcion         = item.Descripcion,
                        PorcentajeDescuento = item.PorcentajeDescuento,
                        IconBackGround      = Color.DeepSkyBlue,
                        Width               = flowLayoutPanel1.Width,
                        Precio              = item.Precio,
                        FotoProducto        = item.FotoProducto,
                    };

                // Agregar control al FlowLayoutPanel
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(e);

                // Agregar el evento clic
                // e.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
                e.ItemClick += new ListItem.ItemClickDelegate(Button_DobleClick);

            }
            
            flowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
            flowLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout();

        }

        private void Button_DobleClick(object sender, ItemSelecionadoArgs e)
        {

            ListItem item = (ListItem)sender;

            ItemSelecionadoArgs args = new ItemSelecionadoArgs(item.SKU, item.Descripcion, item.Reseña, (int)item.Precio, (float)item.PorcentajeDescuento, item.FotoProducto);
            ItemSelecionado(this, args);

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //ListItem item = (ListItem)sender;

            //ItemSelecionadoArgs args = new ItemSelecionadoArgs( item.SKU, item.Descripcion, item.Descuento, item.DatosExtra, (int)item.Precio, (int)item.PrecioMayorista, item.FotoProducto);
            //ItemSelecionado(this, args);

        }

        void UpdateProductos()
        {
            if (items == null)
                return;

            flowLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();

            foreach (Control ctrl in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
                ctrl.Dispose();
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();

            foreach (ItemProducto item in items)
            {
                var e =
                    new ListItem
                    {
                        SKU = item.Sku,
                        Reseña = item.Reseña,
                        Descripcion = item.Descripcion,
                        PorcentajeDescuento = item.PorcentajeDescuento,
                        IconBackGround = Color.DeepSkyBlue,
                        Width = flowLayoutPanel1.Width,
                        Precio = item.Precio,
                        FotoProducto = item.FotoProducto,
                    };

                if( flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count < 0 )
                {
                    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
                }
                else
                    // Agregar control al FlowLayoutPanel
                    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(e);

                // Agregar el evento clic
                // e.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
                e.ItemClick += new ListItem.ItemClickDelegate(Button_DobleClick);

            }
            flowLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout();

        }

    }

    public class ItemProducto
    {
        public string Sku { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public int Descuento { get; set; }
        public string Reseña { get; set; }
        public int Precio { get; set; }
        public float PorcentajeDescuento { get; set; }
        public int Recargo { get; set; }
        public Image FotoProducto { get; set; }

        public ItemProducto(string sku, string descripcion, string reseña, int precio, float porcDescuento, int descuento, int recargo,  Image fotoProducto)
        {

            this.Sku = sku;
            this.Descripcion = descripcion;
            this.Reseña = reseña;
            this.Precio = precio;
            this.PorcentajeDescuento = porcDescuento;
            this.Descuento = descuento;
            this.Recargo = recargo;
            this.FotoProducto = fotoProducto;

        }

    }

    public class ItemSelecionadoArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string Sku { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public string Reseña { get; set; }
        public int Precio { get; set; }
        public  float PorcentajeDescuento { get; set; }
        public Image Image { get; set; }

        public ItemSelecionadoArgs(string sku, string descripcion,  string reseña, int precio, float porcDescuento,  Image imagen)
        {
            this.Sku = sku;
            this.Descripcion = descripcion;
            this.Reseña = reseña;
            this.Precio = precio;
            this.PorcentajeDescuento = porcDescuento;
            this.Image = imagen;
        }

    }

}
```

Pero como les comentaba es un poco pesado.

Alguien me puede indicar cual podría ser una buena practica para hacer el control más manejable para la CPU. O que puedo hacer para mejorar el código.

Gracias a todos!